# AheadWorks blog function getPosts() only getting last 10 posts?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, blogs

We're using the AheadWorks blog plugin on our site. When setting up the category pages, I want to grab all the posts in a certain category. However using the command `<?php $posts = $this->getPosts(); ?>` I only get the latest 10. Is there a way to get all the posts in a certain category?

Comment: Have you check function code? debug that code.

Answer (score 0):

The number of posts displayed is defined by the "Posts per page" global extension option. You can add your own method calculating the number of posts displayed on the page. In the Block file processing the template of the post list the collection limit (the number of products) is defined in the file `app/code/Aheadworks/Blog/Block/PostList.php string 90`